# UIInterfaceOrientation method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

Call is not going into the UIInterfaceOrientation delegate method please help

here is the code

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"potrait");
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your view controller inside another view controller?

Look for  *Technical Q&A QA1688 Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?* in your developer documentation

That will give you a hint of why it isn't working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem last week, and here is what I discovered. If you are using a tab bar, then you must have

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

in every view controller that is added to the TabBarController in order for any of them to rotate. If you only want certain tabs to rotate, you can still achieve this by adding

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
}
```

There may be a similar resolution if you are using a NavigationController, but I haven't run in to that problem yet.